# Add Radio Button into Access DB - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have two radio buttons in my GUI (Male & Female). What I want is that the selected button must be inserted/added into my DB but I can't seem to figure it out. Can anyone help?

```
    Private Sub add_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles add.Click

    If PersonnelID.Text = "" And Fname.Text = "" And Mname.Text = "" And Lname.Text = "" And Address.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please fill all the fields", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error!")

    Else
        Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=|DataDirectory|\faculty.mdb;")
        cn.Open()
        Me.sql = "SELECT * FROM Personnel"
        Me.da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(Me.sql, cn)
        Me.da.Fill(Me.ds, "faculty")
        Me.maxrows = Me.ds.Tables("faculty").Rows.Count

        Dim cb As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
        Me.dsNewRow = Me.ds.Tables("faculty").NewRow

        Me.dsNewRow.Item("PersonnelID") = Me.PersonnelID.Text
        Me.dsNewRow.Item("FirstName") = Me.Fname.Text
        Me.dsNewRow.Item("MiddleName") = Me.Mname.Text
        Me.dsNewRow.Item("LastName") = Me.Lname.Text
        Me.dsNewRow.Item("Birthday") = Me.dtpDateSelection.Value
        Me.dsNewRow.Item("Gender") = Me.MaleRB.Text
        Me.dsNewRow.Item("Gender") = Me.FemaleRB.Text
        Me.dsNewRow.Item("Address") = Me.Address.Text

        Me.ds.Tables("faculty").Rows.Add(Me.dsNewRow)
        Me.da.Update(Me.ds, "faculty")
        cn.Close()
        MsgBox("Personnel Successfully Added")

        Me.ListView2.Items.Clear()
        Me.Personnelload()
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the gender twice.

I really think that should be a radiobuttonlist, and you should use the selected value instead.

Comment: How do I create a radio button list? Do I need to put the buttons inside a Groupbox?

Comment: There's a control called RadioButtonList. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx